# What patterns are possible in Windows for the login field

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication

Our Web Application has a login screen: User can login with their Windows Accounts (the admin can use local accounts).

[image]

The Web Application uses the UserPrincipal in .NET-Framework to match the login name and password. The entered login will be split by the `'\'` into Domain part and SamAccountName part. E.g.:

```
Calamitas\Simon
```

But for local accounts in Windows it is possible to use the computer name instead the domain name:

```
ComputerName\LocalUser
```

And instead for the computer name it is possible to use a dot:

```
.\LocalUser
```

Where can I get a list of all these login patterns?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling `FindByIdentity` then the formats supported are listed in the [IdentityType enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356425(v=vs.110).aspx). This seems to be a subset of the [types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268(v=vs.85).aspx) `GetUserNameEx` can return.

You have most of the important patterns covered already except for `name@example.com`, `name@domain` and `example.com/name`? It might also accept just a `name` but that lookup is going to be slow in a large domain forest.

There are also [distinguished names](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977992.aspx) (`CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM`) but they are hard to parse/validate.

Users are probably not going to use a GUID or a [SID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379597(v=vs.85).aspx) to log in.

If you are trying to validate form input then I would suggest allowing `?*\?*` and `?*@?*` (DOS syntax). Add `S-?-?*` to support SIDs.